# Root partition: make primary partition larger

Tags: partitioning, ssd, gparted

I have a 256GB SSD and thought I would install Windows & Ubuntu in parallel. But now I have no need for Windows at all and need to make my Ubuntu parition larger. It is only 70GB and I have no more space with all the tools like anaconda and so on. I tried to play around in gparted but I can't move the space behind my linux partition. I would appreciate any help cause I don't want to set up my whole System again. Thanks a lot already.
Here is a Screenshot of my current patitions.
[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJmi5.jpg)

Comment: Is sda5 used or have any data, looks more like 1MB used is just the format. If you can remove or backup sda5 then you can move left & expand right. Move will be slow as lots of data and any interruption will total corrupt data. So you must have good backups. If newer UEFI system, probably better to start over, install in UEFI mode with gpt partitioning and restore from backup.

Comment: I don't really know what is in sda5. sda6 is my root linux, and  sda2 was windows which i deleted. So backup my whole system? Basically I just have all the tools installed and not much data at all. But I'd prefer to not setup everything again if I can make the root bigger. I don't understand the part of "UEFI mode", can you pls explain? Thanks

Comment: Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI mode since 2012 and release of Windows 8. So most systems are UEFI hardware. Most Windows 7 systems were the old BIOS/MBR configuration, so if upgrade from that, it probably is BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

you can't resize/move the root partition when booted from the partition itself.
if you see a key icon on the Linux partition, boot from the Ubuntu LiveCD and resize the root partition.

also can you tell what partition is the root one? i can't see "Mount Point" on the screenshot.

Comment: sda6 is my root linux. and I launched gparted on an usb live ubuntu. then deleted the 70gb unallocated and the old windows sda2, which I do want to add to my sda6.

Comment: To resize it, you should have some unallocated space. if you have no unallocated space, you can't resize it. Edit: it should leave an "Unallocated" space after deleting any partition. so if you have some, resize the root partition in the liveUSB. no problems will occur. (except if the linux partition is used by the system, and if it's used, it cannot be resized. you need to go into the live usb to resize it.)